# WiX toolset CNDL0001 Invalid URI when compiling

Tags: wix3.11

I'm running into an issue with an invalid URI when attempting to run the Wix V3.11.2 toolset via Powershell. I'm not sure what is causing the error.

Full error:

```
$ candle.exe Product.wxs
Windows Installer XML Toolset Compiler version 3.11.2.4516
Copyright (c) .NET Foundation and contributors. All rights reserved.

Product.wxs
candle.exe : error CNDL0001 : Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.

Exception Type: System.UriFormatException

Stack Trace:
    at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
    at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
    at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Preprocessor.Process(String sourceFile, Hashtable variables)
    at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Tools.Candle.Run(String[] args)
```

The test file I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" 
           Name="My Software"
           Language="1033"
           Manufacturer="My Company"
           Version="1.0.0.0" 
           UpgradeCode="GUID-HERE">
    
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" 
               Compressed="yes" 
               InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" 
               Title="The main feature" 
               Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>
</Wix>
```

I replaced the UpgradeCode with a placeholder for this post; a unique code
is there when I run it. I've tried installing via the download button from the official site, installing via github exe download, and installing via dotnet tool install. All 3 instances give me the same error. I'm hoping I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Turns out, that is the error message received if the .NET installation is the wrong version, but WiX ends up being installed anyways. For WiX V3.11, the .NET 3.5 framework is needed.